# How to reorder activerecord array based on array of ids

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an existing activerecord array, gotten by the following:

```
@posts = Post.where(["created_at > ?", n_days.days.ago])
```

And I would like to order this array based on a value that needs to be calculated in real-time from multiple columns:

```
posts_array = posts.map { |p| [p.id, f(t, p.x,p.y)] }
```

This gives an array like `[[1,20],[2,11],[3,14], ...]`, which I then sort based on the function value to give `[[1,20],[3,14],[2,11],...]`, and then ultimately get the `order_array` that I want: `[1,3,2,...]`.

What is the best way to then reorder the original `@posts` array based on the new `order_array` `[1,3,2,...]`?  I don't want to touch the database again if possible, since the information is already contained in the `@posts` array.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Do you already have a solution? If yes, please edit your question and add it, to avoid someone just typing what you already did (for example, `sort` followed by `map`)

Comment: I do not already have a solution that reorders the existing @posts array (my primary goal), nor do I have a solution that does just 1 more call (e.g. Post.find([1,3,2,...]) but with order in tact). I would be happy with either solution, but extra points for one that does not touch the database again.

Comment: What about doing it in sql? You create a query that generates a "custom" column for each record (calculated in realtime), than you just use sort('custom_column DESC'), it will heavily improve performance and reduce rails ram usage

Comment: Would that column actually be a database column?  If you can give an example it might be what I want.  Ultimately I don't want to write data to a bunch of columns though, since that seems like it would increase DB load by quite a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the `posts_array` array you could do

```
@posts = Post.where(["created_at > ?", n_days.days.ago])
@posts.sort_by! { |p| f(t, p.x, p.y) }
```

Comment: Did you mean [`sort_by!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21)? Or just `@posts = Post.where(...).sort_by{...}`?

Answer (score 1):

### Getting order_array

The obvious answer is:

```
[[1,20],[2,11],[3,14]].sort{|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1]}.map{|x| x[0]}
 => [1, 3, 2]
```

Not sure if someone can come up with something smarter?

On ruby 2.0, you can use `lazy` to avoid expand the array after the sort (and gain some performance)

```
[[1,20],[2,11],[3,14]].lazy.sort{|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1]}.map{|x| x[0]}
```

### Retrieving posts in the order

The simplest solution is

```
Post.find(order_array).sort{|a,b| order_array.index(a.id) <=> order_array.index(b.id)}
```

But would be better simply

```
order_array.map{|x| Post.find(x)}
```

Or to use your already loaded `@post` list:

```
 order_array.map{|x| @post.find{|y| y.id == x)}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was unclear. I don't have a problem getting the order_array, I have a problem getting the actual posts, based on the order [1,3,2,...].

Comment: fotanus thanks for the answer.  Your last line works beautifully but giving the solution to toro2k for succinctness and eliminating an extra step.  Thanks for yours too!